# Portlet development performence issue

Tags: spring-mvc, portlet, portal

I am creating a portal project on websphere portal server. This project will be developed with the feature of virtual portal. There will be 60-70 portlets deployed on virtual portals.
I have decided to develop portlets using spring mvc framework.
Please some one suggest me that would it be fine to use spring for portlet development as there will be 60-70 portlets on the portal server and as many spring context and associated beans? will there be performance overhead due to those many numbers of contexts and beans.

I there are issues then what can be other options.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you....

Comment: In case of Spring,all Beans are loaded at applications first start only and after that they are reused...addition to it Spring is efficient in managing beans

Comment: thank you for your help....so i hope spring framework will be good to use in portal development.